# Java JPA libraries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

here at work we have an interesting library that's built on top of Hibernate. It's an implementation of a generic DAO but completely filled with futures. In example the following is one of them:

Everything is lazy loaded in our model, but when we want to retrieve some relationships from the database, what we usually do is create a template object of the type we want to retrieve and then set the relationships that we need to fetch. So for example let's suppose the following object.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 @Entity
 @Table(name="MYTABLE")
 public class Type extends BaseAudit<TypeID>{

/**
 * Este campo representa el codigo de autorizacion padre
 *

 */
@Column(name="CODIGOTIPOAUTORIZACIONPADRE")
private Long codigonPadre ;


/**
 * Este campo representa el nombre del tipo de autorizacion
 *

 */
@Column(name="NOMBRETIPOAUTORIZACION")
private String nombreTipoAutorizacion ;



/**
 * 
 *
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGOSISTEMA", referencedColumnName = "SYSID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGOCOMPANIA", referencedColumnName = "COMID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})  
private CompanySystemDto companiaSistemaDTO;




/**
 * 
 *
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({      
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGOCOMPANIA", referencedColumnName = "CODIGOCOMPANIA", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGOSISTEMA", referencedColumnName = "CODIGOSISTEMA", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGOTIPOAUTORIZACIONPADRE", referencedColumnName = "CODIGOTIPOAUTORIZACION", insertable = false, updatable = false),      
})  
private TipoAutorizacionDTO tipoAutorizacionPadreDTO;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="tipoAutorizacionPadreDTO") 
private Collection<TipoAutorizacionDTO> listaAutorizaciones;
    //..... Getters and Setters
```

If we need to fetch any of the relationships it has we would do something like this:

```
Type myType = new Type();
myType.setTipoAutorizacionPadreDTO(new TipoAutorizacionPadreDTO()).
```

In a nutshell.. what the library does is search for any relation objects that are not null in the template, and retrieve them from the database based on some criteria. The critieria could be anything we want. So let's suppose we want all of the Type objects where codigonPadre is 1, the template should be:

```
Type myType = new Type();
myType.setCodigonPadre(1L);
myType.setTipoAutorizacionPadreDTO(new TipoAutorizacionPadreDTO()).
//Code for searching in the database
```

what the above template would do is: Find all the Type instances where the codigonPadre attribute is 1 and fetch the tipoAutorizacionPadreDTO relation for that instance.

I find this "object template" system quite useful, much more that JPQL or any other JPA mechanisms. I know the JPA 2 spec now has the Criteria API in wich we can acomplish something really similar. But the question is... **are there any libraries that manage this style out there ready for use**?

Obviously the library I'm talking about has much more feautures... in example they have what they call CriteriaRestrictions, where we especify the name of the attribute in the template object and the restriction we would like. Example:

```
Type myType = new Type();
myType.setCodigonPadre(1L);
myType.setTipoAutorizacionPadreDTO(new TipoAutorizacionPadreDTO())
myType.setNombreTipoAutorizacion("likeValue");
  myType.addCriteriaRestriction("nombreTipoAutorizacion",RestrictionType.INSENSITIVE_LIKE);
```

This would fetch all the objects where codigonPadre has 1L and nombreTipoAutorizacion has the likeValue inside it's value.

The library has saved me hours of coding, specially when fetching and serching objects, without having to create service methods just to do that specific activities. That's why I would like to find something similar on the internet so that I could use them on future JEE projects.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: FYI, this is called "query by example", and Hibernate has native support for this (although, as it seems, in a more limited way than your API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that Seam 2 ships with something similar. Its called the Seam Application Framework.

But I don't recommend using it, as it provides an extra abstraction and makes it more difficult to understand.